# tmux list all servers, sessions, windows, and panes as a tree

Tags: tmux

**Using `tmux`, how can I list all servers, sessions, windows, and panes in a tree view?**

I'm imagining this would print something like

```
tmux server 1234:
├session 1 [137x80] tty0
│├pane 1   [57x80] *you are here
│├pane 2   [70x80] 
│└window 1 [10x80]
└session 2 [200x200] tty3
 ├pane 1   [100x200]
 ├pane 2   [90x50]
 ├pane 3   [90x50]
 └window 1 [10x200]
```

Is there a tmux command or a script or program for something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press prefix(default crtl-b) and then : to enter command mode, then type:

```
choose-tree
```

You could bind this to something like T by adding the following lines to ~/.tmux.conf:

```
unbind T
bind T choose-tree
```